# How to create Openlayer 3 polygon with arrow?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In research I found one example for arrow in the link below
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/line-arrows.html

and for the vector layer http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.0/examples/vector-layer.html

I need to display a polygon with arrow each side.

Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the first example, from those you provide, and do the following mods.

1. change the geometry type of draw interaction to polygon

   ```
   map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon')
   }));
   ```
2. add a fill color within the styles for your polygon

   ```
   var styles = [
   // linestring
   new ol.style.Style({
     stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
       color: '#ffcc33',
       width: 2
     }),
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
     color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
     })
   })
   ];
   ```
3. Within your style function get the outer ring of your polygon as a linestring

   ```
   var geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(
   feature.getGeometry().getLinearRing(0).getCoordinates()
   );
   ```

thats all!!! and a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c1abw8jy/)

**UPDATE**

For the case of styling just a vector polygon layer with arrows. 
I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c1b7s13y/) to demonstarte. I dont know your case but the fiddle provided is a mess of arrows.

Comment: If the requirement is to load the polygon (with same arrow style) immediate after the map loads then how to do the code (currently polygon is getting displayed only after interaction .) ?

Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Do you mean style a vector polygon layer with arrows? Lets say the 2nd example you provide with arrow style????

Comment: Yes, I mean vector polygon layer with arrow style .

Comment: check the update of my answer. I provide a fiddle to view it in action.

Comment: Wow!!   Thanks a lot.
Is there any way to highlight a starting coordinate ?

In my case I need to display a farming plot(polygon) along with coordinates  labeled as latitude and longitude in each corner.

Your skill is impressive.